# jmeter dont foud the path while is woring in the browser

Tags: jmeter

i can't get a path response in jmter (http://localhost:3000/X) the reponse message is "not found" with 404 cod,while the path (http://localhost:3000) is working with 200 code any one to help please
you can click to see the response of each path

[http://localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP7rS.png)

[http://localhost:3000/X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJTm2.png)

Answer (score 0):

So what?

- If you open https://stackoverflow.com/ in JMeter or browser you will get [HTTP Status Code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)
- If you open https://stackoverflow.com/X in JMeter or browser you will get [HTTP Status Code 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) because this URL doesn't have any candidate page.

If you expect the non-existent page to return HTTP status code 404 and don't want JMeter to mark this result as failed - add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter) as a child of this request and configure it like:

[image]

Comment: i didn't mean X as a charachter i mean that every thing i add in the path after http://localhost:3000/... gives not found ;  for example (http://localhost:3000/addimage) its working on my browser but i'ts not on jmeter